# Elegant pattern for multiple constructors

Tags: vb.net

Assuming an object with the following code...

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.Name = "Default Name"
    Initialize()
End Sub

Public Sub New(CustomName as String)
    Me.Name = CustomName
    Initialize()
End Sub

Private Sub Initialize()
    'Initialize some other properties
End Sub
```

Is there a more elegant pattern for this use case?  Some way where one constructor could call the other constructor and eliminate the need for the Initialize() method?

Comment: `MyClass.New` would call a different ctor such as the simple one from the one which takes a string; the all the Initialize code could just be there.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3b35kyk(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could write one constructor with all the needed parameters and then write the rest with a call to Me.Constructor() without anything else in the method block that supplies the defaults.

```
Public Sub New(CustomName as String)
    Me.Name = CustomName
End Sub

Public Sub New()
    Me.New("Default Name")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's a VB syntax for constructor chaining in the C# sense, but if I remember correctly VB can invoke other constructors internally by calling `Me.New()`.  Which is kind of the same thing.  So you should be able to do something like this:

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.New("Default Name")
End Sub

Public Sub New(CustomName as String)
    Me.Name = CustomName
    'Initialize some other properties
End Sub
```